# How does the TLS cipher suite DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM8 work without hashing algorithm

Tags: tls, authenticated-encryption, modes-of-operation, openssl

I came across cipher suites without hashing algorithm, when inspecting the mbedTLS (previously Polar SSL) [TLS cipher suite list](https://tls.mbed.org/supported-ssl-ciphersuites).

For example:

- TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CCM-8 (OpenSSL: DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM8)
- TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CCM-8 (OpenSSL: DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM8)

As stated in [other questions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17691/why-does-aes-gcm-need-a-hash-mac-in-tls), the hashing algorithm has applications in TLS, even with AEAD ciphers/modes of operation.

How do these TLS cipher suites work without hashing algorithm and how do they compare to their counterparts with a hashing algorithm, considering the security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These Cipher Suites are defined in [RFC 6655](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6655) and use [TLS v1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246)'s default: [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2).

[To quote it from the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6655#page-4):

> These ciphersuites make use of the default TLS 1.2 Pseudorandom
> Function (PRF), which uses HMAC with the SHA-256 hash function.

The default-ness of SHA-256 is probably inferred from the following parapgraph from [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-5):

> In this section, we define one PRF, based on HMAC.  This PRF with the
> SHA-256 hash function is used for all cipher suites defined in this
> document and in TLS documents published prior to this document when
> TLS 1.2 is negotiated.  New cipher suites MUST explicitly specify a
> PRF and, in general, SHOULD use the TLS PRF with SHA-256 or a
> stronger standard hash function.