# If all encrypt algorithms in TLS1.3 ciphersuites are AEAD , why do they keep including a Hash algorithm?

Tags: sha-256, chacha, aes-gcm

In TLS1.3 all allowed algorithms included in cipher suites are AEAD, which means they don't just encrypt but they authenticate too (thus if I don't misunderstand, they give not only confidentiality but also integrity/authentication. So, then...why it's necessary to include a Hash algorithm in the cipher suite? I mean...why isn't ChaCha20 (or AES-GCM, etc) enough so Poly1305 (or SHA256, etc) should be necessary?

Comment: Mostly the same as for AEAD in TLS1.2, which was answered years ago, although 1.3 uses standard HKDF instead of 'custom' PRF: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17691/why-does-aes-gcm-need-a-hash-mac-in-tls https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26410/whats-the-gcm-sha-256-of-a-tls-protocol https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39590/whats-the-hash-for-in-ecdhe-rsa-aes-gcm-sha https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115605/how-is-hash-used-with-aead-based-ciphers-in-tls

Comment: Basically, the mode of operation is used for the encryption of data. But you need a hash-based functionality for everything that isn't covered by the transmission of data, e.g. in the key agreement.

Comment: Thanks to all!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [RFC 8446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446), the hash is used for:

1. The transcript hash, covering every message in the handshake to authenticate it during key agreement and certificate verification ([§4.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.4.1)).
2. Deriving various session keys from raw key agreement material and transcript hash with HKDF ([§7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-7.1)).
3. Deriving key material for protocols based on the key negotiated in a TLS session ([RFC 5705](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5705)).

Answer (score 1):

There are other tools in TLS 1.3 that you didn't list. From section  [E.1.1.
in RFC8446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#page-145)

> E.1.1.  Key Derivation and HKDF
> Key derivation in TLS 1.3 uses HKDF as defined in [RFC5869] and its
> two components, HKDF-Extract and HKDF-Expand.

HKDF is HMAC-based Extract-and-Expand Key Derivation Function and defined in [rfc5869](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869)

The HMAC requires the Cryptographic Hash algorithm  specified in the cipher
suite, these are SHA256 or SHA384.